# Defining an Ehresmann Connection Using Linear Connection

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

In some places that I have seen, given the covariant derivative $\nabla$ of a linear connection on a vector bundle $\pi: E\rightarrow M$ (dim(M)=k), an Ehresmann connection is defined in the following way:

Find $k$ local sections $\sigma_i$ of $E$ such that $\nabla(\sigma_i)=0$ and then 
compute the horizontal space by taking images of $T_xM$ by $D\sigma_i: T_xM \rightarrow T_{x,\sigma_i(x)}E$.

But as far as I know such sections would only exist when curvature vanishes? So what am I missing here?

Comment: The condition on the vanishing of the covariant derivatives should be a punctual one, not a local one and it might be formulated so to involve only one section. That is, the condition should read  "Given $p \in \pi^{-1}(x)$ with $x \in M$, find a local section $\sigma$ of $E$ over a neighbordhood of $U \ni x$ such that $\sigma(x) = p$ and $(\nabla \sigma_i)(x)=0$. Then compute the horizontal space by taking the image of $D\sigma : T_xM \to T_{x, p}E$". In this way, we can infer nothing about the Frobenius integrability of the horizontal distribution i.e. about the vanishing of the curvature.

Comment: This seems more right I will reflect on it for a while thanks.